# Reset Unit ID or Machine ID in JUJU

Tags: juju, maas

How can we reset unit-id or machine-id? so when it tries to assign id it start form 1, not where it was left before?

Answer (score 1):

Every time a new machine or unit is created it increments that count in the model. In order to reset the counts you would need a new model.

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/devel/models
- https://jujucharms.com/docs/devel/models-adding

Comment: Could you please give me more detail about new model, is there any related link?